# what does positive index mean in addRule(selector,style,index)?

Tags: javascript

I know that in `addRule(selector,style,index)` , index is -1 by default meaning it is appended to the end of the rules, but I have seen people use index 1, what does this mean?

Comment: It means that the rule will be inserted at position `1`, the second rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [`iIndex [in, optional]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa358796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - Integer that specifies the zero-based position
>   in the rules collection where the new style rule should be placed.

`-1` is the default, meaning it's inserted at the end.

`0` means it'll be inserted right at the beginning.

and `1` means it'll be inserted in position `1`, which is second (as it's zero-based).

Answer (score 1):

The index argument is a zero-based position in the rules collection where the new rule will be placed.  A "1" means the second position in the collection.